# MPI with 32-bit and 64-bit nodes error

Tags: types, 64-bit, mpi, 32-bit

I am developing a simple MPI application which should work both with 32-bit and 64-bit nodes. As I read here, MPI supports such a thing: https://books.google.bg/books?id=isTBDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA163&lpg=PA163&dq=MPI+datatype+32+and+64-bit+nodes&source=bl&ots=w3WvUvjkmD&sig=IlFGgpu2-N2J1b9pwPEmUKj6e0I&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi55-qz76fOAhVIsxQKHciJDTIQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=MPI%20datatype%2032%20and%2064-bit%20nodes&f=false.

However, I experience the error that after the packet is send from the 32-bit master to the 64-bit master it is not received. I send using the MPI_UNSIGNED_LONG_LONG datatype. Do you have any idea where is my mistake?

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: sizeof() gives that both types are 8 bytes... It may be useful -> I use mpich2 and the 32-bit node is a Raspberry Pi Zero, while the 64-bit node is a Intel Core i5 CPU.

Comment: The Intel x86_64 CPUs are little-endian, while the ARM CPUs are bi-endian. However, in the kernel configuration on the RPi it is also little-endian....

Comment: Although many MPI implementations advertise heterogeneous support, it is often not built by default as the conversion process imposes some performance penalty. Check that your MPICH does support heterogeneous computing (no idea how though).